# ¿Qué puedo hacer con este error ? ValueError: Expected singleton: sale.order.line(26, 27)

Tags: python, odoo

tengo un problemita que espero puedan ayudarme a solucionarlo.
Estoy modificando el botón 'Confirmar Venta' de la vista sale.order.form. La idea es esto, es que cuando presione este botón me redireccione inmediatamente al inventario (stock.picking.form). Esto funciona perfectamente, pero cuando valido la función para me redireccione solo cuando sea un producto de tipo stockable, funciona solo cuando ingreso UN producto. El error se produce cuando agrego mas de un producto en la order, tal como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la funcion del boton 'Confirmar venta'

```
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
    for order in self:
        order.state = 'sale'
        if self.env.context.get('send_email'):
            self.force_quotation_send()
        order.order_line._action_procurement_create()
        if not order.project_id:
            for line in order.order_line:
                if line.product_id.invoice_policy == 'cost':
                    order._create_analytic_account()
                    break
    if self.env['ir.values'].get_default('sale.config.settings', 'auto_done_setting'):
        self.action_done()
```

****AQUÍ COMIENZA LA MODIFICACION DE LA FUNCION****************

```
if self.order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type in 'product':        

    action = self.env.ref('stock.action_picking_tree_all')

    result = {
        'name': action.name,
        'help': action.help,
        'type': action.type,
        'view_type': action.view_type,
        'view_mode': action.view_mode,
        'target': action.target,
        'context': action.context,
        'res_model': action.res_model,
    }

    pick_ids = sum([order.picking_ids.ids for order in self], [])

    if len(pick_ids) > 1:
        result['domain'] = "[('id','in',["+','.join(map(str, pick_ids))+"])]"
    elif len(pick_ids) == 1:
        form = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form', False)
        form_id = form.id if form else False
        result['views'] = [(form_id, 'form')]
        result['res_id'] = pick_ids[0]
    return result
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme con este problema de como validar la función de manera que pueda ingresar mas de un producto. Tengo entendido que este tipo de problema es porque se está validando solo para un producto, cuando en la orden estoy ingresando dos. Muchas Gracias a todos.

Comment: Otro día pon la versión de odoo :(

Answer (score 2):

Según veo tu error esta en la parte `if self.order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.type in 'product':`. El problema es que tienes un conjunto de objetos "sale_line" (id 26 y 27), y estas llamando al "product_id" sin iterar ese dataset.

La solucion es simple. Solamente cambia

```
self.order_line
```

por

```
order
```

y se solucionará.